# Database Update with Prepared Statement in JSF

Tags: mysql, sql, jsf, jsf-2, javabeans

I have `mainpage.xhtml` which displays entire records in my database and allows me to edit them. In case of clicling **Edit** button it calls `mainPageController.edit()` function which fills _bilgi variable in MainPageConroller class then it redirects to `edit.xhtml` page.

In **edit.xhtml** page it basically displays the values of _bilgi that are filled before in `MainPageController class`. There's no problem till here(probably there is but I am not aware of it.)

When I want to update one of those variables such as *baslik* I created a method in **MainPageController** which calls `updateBilgi(_bilgi)` in **bilgiDAO class.**

In `UpdateBilgi` it is pretty clear what it does yet it is not updating the table. It is interesting for me that when I debug and follow the variables, everything goes well but in the end it just does not update.

Another thing is when I put just a string in BilgilerDAO such is  `ps.setString(1, "aqa1")` it works but `ps.setString(2, bilgi.getBaslik())` does not eventho bilgi.getBaslik() returns the changed value.

What could be wrong? 
Thank you for the answers in advance.

I hope I am clear enough.

Edit: I found the glitch. in BilgilerDAO the function `updateBilgi(Bilgi bilgi)`
the variable `bilgi` doesn't get the id from _bilgi but gets other variables. Why it wouldn't get the id?

**mainpage.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="bilgiForm">
    <h:dataTable id="bilgiTable" value="#{mainPageController.bilgiListesi}"
        var="bilgiler" border="1">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Başlık" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{bilgiler.baslik}" />
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:outputText value="Başlık" />
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Bilgi Metni" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{bilgiler.bilgi}" />
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:outputText value="Bilgi Metni" />
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>


        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Bilgi Metni" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{bilgiler.bilgi}" />
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:outputText value="Bilgi Metni" />
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Bilgi Metni" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:graphicImage
                value="https://canakkale.000webhostapp.com/showImage.php/?name=#{bilgiler.img.name}" />
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:outputText value="Bilgi Metni" />
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <fcore:facet name="header">Edit</fcore:facet>
            <h:commandButton action="edit" value="Edit"
                actionListener="#{mainPageController.edit()}">
                <fcore:param name="id" value="#{bilgiler.id}" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>




    <fcore:view>
        <h:form>
            <fcore:view>
                <h:form>
                    <h1>Update</h1>
                    <h:panelGrid border="" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="20"
                        columns="3">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Bilgi ID" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{mainPageController._bilgi.id}"
                            readonly="true" required="true" requiredMessage="Id is Required"
                            id="bilgiID">
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:message for="bilgiID" />

                        <h:outputLabel value="Tag" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{mainPageController._bilgi.tag}"
                            readonly="true" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Tag Girmeniz Gereklidir." id="bilgiTag">
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:message for="bilgiTag" />
                        <h:outputLabel value="Başlık" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{mainPageController._bilgi.baslik}"
                            required="true" requiredMessage="Başlık Girmeniz Gereklidir."
                            id="bilgiBaslik">
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:message for="bilgiBaslik" />


                        <h:outputLabel value="Bilgi Metni" />
                        <h:inputTextarea value="#{mainPageController._bilgi.bilgi}"
                            required="true" requiredMessage="Başlık Girmeniz Gereklidir."
                            id="bilgiBilgi">
                        </h:inputTextarea>
                        <h:message for="bilgiBilgi" />


                        <h:outputLabel value="Image URL" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{mainPageController._bilgi.img.name}"
                            required="true" requiredMessage="Başlık Girmeniz Gereklidir."
                            readonly="true" id="bilgiImgName">
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:message for="bilgiImgName" />

                        <h:outputLabel value="Başlık" />
                        <input type="file" value="#{mainPageController._bilgi.img.image}" />
                        <h:commandButton action="#{mainPageController.updateRecord()}"
                            value="Update">
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
            </fcore:view>


        </h:form>
    </fcore:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**MainPageController Class**

```
 @ManagedBean
    public class MainPageController implements Serializable {

        List<Bilgi> bilgiListesi = new ArrayList<Bilgi>();
        private Bilgi _bilgi = new Bilgi();
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        BilgilerDAO bilgiDao = new BilgilerDAO();
        ImageDAO imgDao = new ImageDAO();

        public MainPageController() {// Default Constructor
            try {
                bilgiListesi = showAllRecords();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public List<Bilgi> showAllRecords() throws SQLException {
            return bilgiDao.getAllBilgiler();
        }

        public List<Image> showAllImages() throws Exception {
            return imgDao.getAllImages();

        }

        public void updateRecord() {
            try {
                bilgiDao.updateBilgi(_bilgi);
                //imgDao.updateImage(_bilgi.getImg());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void edit() {
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            int id;
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
            id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            try {
                bilgiListesi = bilgiDao.getAllBilgiler();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (Bilgi bilgi : bilgiListesi) {
                if (bilgi.getId() == id) {
                    _bilgi.setBaslik(bilgi.getBaslik());
                    _bilgi.setBilgi(bilgi.getBilgi());
                    _bilgi.setImg(bilgi.getImg());
                    _bilgi.setTag(bilgi.getTag());
                    _bilgi.setId(bilgi.getId());
                }

            }
        }

        public void edit(Bilgi bilgi) {
            for (Bilgi existing : getBilgiListesi()) {
                existing.setEditable(false);
            }
            bilgi.setEditable(true);
        }


    }
```

BilgilerDAO

```
@Override
    public String updateBilgi(Bilgi bilgi) throws Exception {
        String sql = "UPDATE bilgiler SET bilgi=?, baslik =? WHERE id=? ";
        ps = DatabaseConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1, "aqa1");
        ps.setString(2, bilgi.getBaslik());
        ps.setInt(3, bilgi.getId());

        int ex = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (ex > 0) {
            System.err.println("coodld");
        }
        ps.close();
        return "mainpage";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved the issue.

```
<h:inputText value="#{mainPageController._bilgi.id}" readonly="true" required="true" requiredMessage="Id is Required" id="bilgiID">
```

in this xhtml line **readonly="true"** caused it return null. I removed it now it works how I wanted. Though, I still want them to be displayed but not editable.